# Spring JDBC 404 null on simple get

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to learn how to connect to the database with Spring JDBC.  Right now, I'm just trying to make a simple get request to retrieve the contents of a table in H2.  However, every time I run the test, I get a 404 error:

```
12:05:41.237 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - Created GET request for "http://localhost:8080/rides"
12:05:41.339 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate - GET request for "http://localhost:8080/rides" resulted in 404 (null); invoking error handler

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 null

    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:94)
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:79)
    at org.springframework.web.client.ResponseErrorHandler.handleError(ResponseErrorHandler.java:63)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:777)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:730)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:686)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:631)
    at com.example.RideResourcesTest.testGetRides(RideResourcesTest.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:237)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

The code for my test is:
public class RideResourcesTest {

```
@Test
public void testGetRides() {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    ResponseEntity<List<Ride>> rideResponse = restTemplate.exchange(
            "http://localhost:8080/rides", HttpMethod.GET,
            null, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Ride>>() {
            }
    );
    List<Ride> rides = rideResponse.getBody();

    for (Ride ride : rides) {
        System.out.println("Ride Name: " + ride.getName());
    }
}
```

And my repository implementations is:

```
@Repository("rideDAO")
public class RideDAOImpl implements RideDAO {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public List<Ride> getRides() {
        List<Ride> rides = jdbcTemplate.query("select * from ride;", new RideRowMapper());
        return rides;
    }
}
```

And my Service implementation:

```
@Service("rideManager")
public class RideManagerImpl implements RideManager {

    @Autowired
    private RideDAO dao;

    @Override
    public List<Ride> getRides() {
        return dao.getRides();
    }
}
```

Finally, my controller is as follows:

```
@Controller
public class RideResource {

    @Autowired
    private RideManager manager;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/rides", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody List<Ride> getRides() {
        return manager.getRides();
    }
}
```

I don't see anything out of place in my code, so I'm wondering what else could cause this.  Part of me suspects I could have done something wrong with the Tomcat setup, but that doesn't make any sense to me; if that were the case, it likely wouldn't start, and it seems to deploy the war correctly each time I use it.

Edit:  Here is my Spring Configuration files, to register the components of my app, and to connect to the database:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.3.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.example"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/~/test"/>
        <property name="username" value="sa"/>
        <property name="password" value=""/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <display-name>jdbcSpring</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jdbcSpringServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/config/servlet-config.xml
                classpath:jdbc-config.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jdbcSpringServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>

    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Edit: Also, this code is part of a tutorial to show how to use Spring JDBC.  I'm trying to get the code to work on my own instance of Intellij.  The maker of the course posted his code on GitHub, [here](https://github.com/bh5k/ride_tracker).

Comment: Are you sure that your controller is registered in Spring environment?
JDBC has nothing to do with this issue.

Comment: It seems to be; I'm using component-scan to register the classes in the base package.  I'll include my Spring configuration file to show it.

Comment: Can you share web.xml configuration

Comment: I just posted it.

Answer (score 0):

what I can see in your error is that,

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 null
```

you are trying to connect to your client inside your code and the client is not up.

if you querying the URL through rest Template, that client should be up first.